# Reusing stopwords and other files in Solr multicore

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I have a multicore setup for solr, the directory structure of which goes like

```
-multicore
|-core0
|--conf
|---schema.xml
|---solrconfig.xml
|---stopwords
|---synonyms
|-core1
|--conf
|---schema.xml
|---solrconfig.xml
|---stopwords
|---synonyms
```

Both of these cores essentially use the same stop words and synonyms file. Is there a way, both these files could be located at a common place and both the cores read it from there?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [CoreAdmin](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin) documentation, you can

> specify properties in solr.xml which can be used in the solrconfig.xml and schema.xml files.

So as an example you could create something similar to the following:

```
 <solr persistent="true" sharedLib="lib">
   <property name="synonymns" value="<your path here>/synonyms.txt" />
   <property name="stopwords" value="<your path here>/stopwords.txt" />
   <cores adminPath="/admin/cores">
     <core name="core0" instanceDir="core0"/>
     <core name="core1" instanceDir="core1" />
  </cores>
</solr>
```

Hopefully this should get you started, you will obviously want/need to modify the solr.xml settings to meet your specific needs. Also there are a few other options for how the properties can be defined and the use of defaults. Please refer to the documentation for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is any elegant way with the latest releases.
You can check using the absolute path of the stopwords file.
We have just created a symbolic link to a common shared files which are updated avoiding duplicates.